# Website url skipping a slash

Tags: php, css

I'm not sure what code to actually post here so I will ask u and update the post when asked for certain code.

But as stated in the title.
My website url skips a slash.

Website url: [The Website URL](http://www.worldofthegods.com/armory)

I hope u guys can help me out!

Kind regards,
Mikey

Comment: *"My website url skips a slash."* When you click on a link? How do we replicate your issue without going to your site?

Comment: Do you have any server redirection configuration? Which server are you using? Apache? It works if you access by HTTPS directly.

Comment: Looks like a rewrite issue. If you visit via HTTPS directly it works. Looks like your rewrite from http to https is missing a slash somewhere.